# Is adding html5shiv enough?

Tags: html, wordpress, html5, markup

I want to start using HTML5 markup in my next WP theme and I wondered if adding html5shiv is enough for adding compatibility for IE8+ browsers.

I'm talking about the simple stuff such as `aside`, `article` and `header`, not the form stuff.

Comment: Did you read its documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It will make those elements compatible with IE6+, Safari 4+ and Firefox 3+.

Comment: Awesome thanks! What else does it add? Is there any doc available?

Comment: You can read the repo in github here: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv , also remember to have a look at the Wiki at the right tab.

Comment: No. It is not enough if their browser doesn't support JavaScript or doesn't have it enabled.

Comment: It's a JavaScript file, users of the script are targeting browsers with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: You missed the point entirely.